# How to properly secure a resource server, but allow public clients to have access in a machine-machine style without user interaction

Tags: oauth

My scenario is this, I have my web API that I want to protect from external people, but I want to allow access for my own applications that could be running in windows forms/android/ios/etc... [considered public clients].

I'm using identity server 3 ([Github link](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3)) as my identity provider implementation.

My initial thought was generate a client id + secret and put that (somehow) in all clients, but this is considered dangerous because public clients should not have secrets on it, because with more or less effort you can always have access to it.

So what is the best way to protect my web API?
I have control of web API, clients and Identity server, because they are all my products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rate-Limit the API calls. Make sure every installation gets a unique ID (see UUID). Limit the calls to your API per UUID and IP to a strict limit.

But be careful: sometimes, multiple legit users use the same IP address. So you should set your limit to about 2-3 times of what a single client will consume.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my case the clients can use different IP every day. But with that UUID is not the same as having a client id and client secret? In what way is that solution more secure than id + secret? Anyone can extract the UUID and do the call.

Comment: What is `secure` to you? If anyone can download the Application and access your data thorough it its really just a matter of preference whether they do so using you Application or you API. If you expose your data through public clients, your data becomes public information. There is no way around that.
The UUID approach saves you from abuse and make DOS attacks significantly harder. It does not protect information.

Comment: Your point about DOS is a good one, I didn't think about. 
Ok so let's say that I'm amazon and I have a couple of guys on the street using some devices (android/windows/ios/whatever) and I have a WEB API's that I want to restrict access, only those devices are allowed to access.

Comment: Thats impossible. Anyone who has access to the device running a public client can use your API. The only thing that you can do (through permission checks and rate limiting), is, that the API cannot be used differently than it would be by your public client.